# Trovebox (OpenPhoto) setup hangs/fails at final step 3

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, mysql

I've been following the install instructions found [here](http://theopenphotoproject.org/documentation/guide/InstallationUbuntuApache) about how to install and configure Trovebox on a Ubuntu server running Apache:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
Apache: 2.4.7 
MySQL: 5.5.37
PHP: 5.5.9
```

Everything works fine up to the point where I'm running the actual setup of Trovebox. I can access the interface, go through steps 1 and 2 (create user and select storage medium), but after the third step I just get redirected to a empty html.

The third step revolves around the MySQL credentials that were created for the software. I've verified that the credentials work on the database, and also tried (in hope of debugging the issue) to use the root access without that solving the issue. I'm not sure if a db access is the issue but its the only thing I can think of atm.

I've also gone through all Apache and MySQL logs I can locate, and can't see anything going wrong.

Apache (www-data) has write privileges on the Trovebox location.

All hints, tips and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was encountering this problem as well and fixed it by loading the mcrypt extension in my php.ini. To do this, I did the following:

- Edit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
- Add the line `extension=mcrypt.so`
- Save
- Restart apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`)

Comment: Lack of mcrypt was the source. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution ( Tested once, Then reproduced succesfully again )

Not sure why the project maintainers dont provide this workaround but here it is.

### create a user.sql file with these contents.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
id varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User''s email address',
password varchar(64) NOT NULL,
extra text NOT NULL,
timestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### create db user table, prompt for password

```
mysql newblankdatabasename < user.sql -p
```

Now enter this as the database in your user setup and setup will complete succesfully.

Alternatively use the install script which I fixed and submitted a pull request for.

https://github.com/russmac/frontend/commit/66c2440778830d0e7f55fadc6d5cdf8192522a6b

https://github.com/russmac/frontend/blob/master/documentation/guides/InstallationUbuntuApache.sh

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I'd like to run this script on my server, but I have an existing VirtualMin installation. Is it likely to cause havoc for me?

Comment: Junto, that shouldn't be an issued. Virtualmin interoperates comfortable with almost any configuration. This does *seem* to assume a mod_php configuration, which isn't really recommended in any shared hosting system, but Virtualmin supports it (and you can still use the default mod_fcgid+suexec PHP configuration for other sites).

Answer (score 0):

What version of the code are you using? If you view the source if the empty page is it also blank?

First, make sure your *user* table is empty or doesn't already have an entry for the email address you're using. Sometimes if a problem occurs the record is created but not cleaned up. That's something we should open an issue for.

Second, make sure the database is already created. The tables should not exist though.

If those don't work then change the log level and see if anything shows up in the Apache error log.

To change the log level you can add a file at *src/configs/override.ini* with the following.

```
[epi]
logLevels="crit,warn,info"
```

You might also want to add this to *override.ini* depending on what code you're using. See Github issue [1267](https://github.com/photo/frontend/issues/1267) and [1495](https://github.com/photo/frontend/issues/1495) for details.

```
[site]
mode="prod"
```